# Implicit cast using Linq

Tags: c#, .net, extension-methods, linq-to-objects

Say I have a list with integers (`var identifiers = Enumerable.Empty<int>()`).

With this list I can cast the individual items to another type:

```
var castedIdentifiersLong = identifiers.Cast<long>();
var castedIdentifiersString = identifiers.Cast<string>();
```

We can use `Select<TSource, TTarget>()` to use implicit casting:

```
var mappedIdentifiersLong = identifiers.Select<int, long>(x => x);
var mappedIdentifiersString = identifiers.Select<int, string>(x => x);
```

Obviously the last statement fails, because `int` cannot be implicitly casted to `string`. This is intentionally.

Is there a way that I can define an extension method (say `CastImplicitly<T>`), where I can only define one of the two generic types and it would figure out the first type from the source enumerable?

```
var unwanted = identifiers.ImplicitCast<string>();
var wanted = identifiers.ImplicitCast<long>();
```

In this case `unwanted` shouldn't even compile, because `int` isn't implicitly castable to `string`. But on the other hand, `wanted` should compile, because it is implicitly castable to `long`.

Comment: Are you talking about TypeOf method?

Comment: @Valentin No, of some compile-time check which doesn´t exist in this form

Comment: `var castedIdentifiersString = identifiers.Cast<string>();` crashes on non-empty int sequence, if you begin to enumerate `castedIdentifiersString`; it is unclear if you see that issue

Comment: No, that's not how generic type inference works.  It either has to infer all the types or you have to specify all the types.

Comment: I see one 'unclear what you're asking'-close vote, could you elaborate? `OfType` isn't usable because it's an `int`, and not a `long`. ASh: I do see that, it's something I just use to emphasize the problem (its `Cast<T>`-able, but not (implicitly) castable).

Comment: @Caramiriel I'm guessing it's because though you seem to be clear in what you're asking for, there's no indication as to why you need/want this functionality. Which kind of boils the questions down to "can I do X, because X would be cool?" Which seems like a possible X/Y problem. Perhaps if you gave an example of a real-world problem this solution would solve?

Comment: I see. I find myself using linq-queries over complex types. In the end there's a property with type `int`, but the method I want to call, only accepts `IEnumerable<long>`. Therefor it would be nice skipping the mapping code (`Select<int,long>(x=>x)`), because the `x=>x` doesn't make much sense to type/read.

Comment: @Caramiriel If I read you correctly, you basically want to Cast without casting. You want `ImplicitCast` to work without you having to call it?

Comment: Well, I want to `Cast<T>` but letting the compiler know me when it's not implicitly castable, if that makes sense :)

Comment: @DanielCook It sounds more like the OP wants a compile-time check for an invalid cast which `Cast` does not do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way that I can define an extension method (say `CastImplicitly<T>`), where I can only define one of the two generic types and it would figure out the first type from the source enumerable?

Not if the input is generic. The compiler cannot partially infer generic parameters - you either have to specify all generic parameters or none and let the compiler infer.

Even if you *could*, the compiler still would not allow an implicit cast between generic types.

If you want the compiler to identify invalid casts at compile-time you could do an explicit cast:

```
var mappedIdentifiersString = identifiers.Select(x => (string)x);  // fails at compile time if x is an int.
```

It may not catch *every* possible invalid cast at compile-time (e.g. casts to/from `object` are always allowed at compile-time) but it does fail for your specific `int` to `string` scenario.